# Wifi connection stopped working after upgrade

Tags: wireless, upgrade

My wifi connection has been working flawlessly for 2 years running ubuntu 11.04 at first and even after upgrading to 12.04. A few minutes ago, the connection to my router suddenly stopped dropped; this was after a restart (it had been connected right up until then). The network icon on top indicates that it is trying to connect and after a while it stops and tells me I that I am disconnected. All 3 of the other devices that are connected to the router maintain access as usual so I do not think it has anything to do with the router itself. Also, I found out that I have no problem connecting to the hotspot of my cell phone - even though my computer can't connect to my router.

I have also reinstalled Ubuntu onto my laptop; during the installation, the wifi is present as wlan0 but after the upgrade it's changed to eth1.

Any ideas on what the problem may be or tips on how to debug it?
Thank you for your time and help.

lspci:

```
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

syslog:

```
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) starting connection 'wireless'
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless): access point 'wireless' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Feb 9 23:58:14 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: get_secret_flags: assertion `is_secret_prop (setting, secret_name, error)' failed
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless): connection 'wireless' has security, and secrets exist. No new secrets needed.
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'wireless'
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Feb 9 23:58:24 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook wpa_supplicant[1159]: Trying to associate with 00:14:bf:dc:74:26 (SSID='wireless' freq=2462 MHz)
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook wpa_supplicant[1159]: Associated with 00:14:bf:dc:74:26
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook wpa_supplicant[1159]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:14:bf:dc:74:26 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook wpa_supplicant[1159]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:14:bf:dc:74:26 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=].
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network 'wireless'.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2897
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: All rights reserved.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient:
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook NetworkManager[963]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth1/ac:81:12:7a:e7:15
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: Sending on LPF/eth1/ac:81:12:7a:e7:15
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: Sending on Socket/fallback
Feb 9 23:58:26 ProBook dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.100792] net_ratelimit: 2 callbacks suppressed
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.100800] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rate (-1)
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.100808] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rssi (-1)
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.100902] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rate (-1)
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.100908] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rssi (-1)
Feb 9 23:58:27 ProBook kernel: [ 532.175977] userif-2: sent link down event.
```

Comment: This is a bug confirmed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1114281